# https for stream_context_create

Tags: php, api, magento2

Iam new to trying like this, I have trying to get the token with https in magento2, it not working here my code

```
<?php
$base_url="https://myurl.com/";
$domain="myurl.com";
$url = $base_url.'index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$body = '{"username":"ApiUser", "password":"ApiPass"}';

$context_options = array (
        'https' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header'=> "Content-type: application/json"
            'content' => $body
            ),
        'ssl' => array('SNI_enabled'=>true,'SNI_server_name'=> $domain)
        );

$context = stream_context_create($context_options);
$token = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context));
echo $token; echo "<br/>";
?>
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: its doesn't get token value, url with http-> it gives token value, but if the url with https, it won't get the token value

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the super late reply, but was just looking for this solution as well, to use https URL instead of http.

FROM the PHP manual page/example, the context should not be https, but rather http.:
http://php.net/manual/it/function.stream-context-create.php#74795

INCORRECT:

```
$context_options = array (
    'https' => array ()
)
```

CORRECT:

```
$context_options = array (
    'http' => array ()
)
```

of if you need more SSL options, this comment:
http://php.net/manual/it/function.stream-context-create.php#110158

```
$contextOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer'   => true,
        'cafile'        => __DIR__ . '/cacert.pem',
        'verify_depth'  => 5,
        'CN_match'      => 'secure.example.com'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to create stream context with `stream_context_create` when working in `SSL` environment is to omit verification! This works just fine for me when I want to retrieve data with `file_get_contents`:

```
stream_context_create([
    'http' => [ /* your options here - eg: */ 'method' => 'POST', ],
    // 'https' => 'DON'T forget there is no "https", only "http" like above',
    'ssl'  => [ // here comes the actual SSL part...
        'verify_peer'      => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ]
]);
```

---

[php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php):

> `verify_peer` `boolean`
> Require verification of SSL certificate used.
> Defaults to TRUE.

> `verify_peer_name` `boolean`
> Require verification of peer name.
> Defaults to TRUE.

Comment: @imclickingmaniac could you explain why you find this "should lead to instant ban"?

Comment: Because searching anywhere for `curl ssl connection` or `php <here ssl/cert error>` will pop up tones of answers like yours which are bad in its core.
1. "solution" will work only if you don't need certificate to authenticate 2. "solution" is unsecure. SSL was created for security. You just switch it off. 3. Responses like yours make it harder to find proper solution - fixing SSL configuration errors.